# Executing both if and else statements in the last block

Tags: python, if-statement

```
RAM = int(input("RAM amount: "))
if RAM >= 8:
 print ("Your RAM is good")
else:
 print ("not enough RAM")

HDD = int(input("Enter HDD or SSD storage space: "))
if HDD >=55:
 print("You have enough space")
else:
 print("You do not have enough space")

OS = input("Input Windows version ex: Windows 10: ")
if OS=="Windows 10":
 print ("You meet the minimum OS requirement")
if OS=="Windows 8.1":
 print ("You meet the minimum OS requirement")
if OS=="Windows 7":
 print ("You meet the minimum OS requirement")
if OS=="Linux":
 print("This OS is not supported")
if OS=="Mac":
 print("This OS is not supported")
else:
 print("Your OS does not meet the minimum requirements")
```

Not sure why both "You meet the minimum OS requirement" and "This OS is not supported" both print when I input a value.

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` blocks are not complement. Make them complement by using elif.
Otherwise the else statement will complement with the last if statement, this is exactly the reason why you were getting two outputs instead of just one.

```
OS = input("Input Windows version ex: Windows 10: ")
if OS == "Windows 10":
    print ("You meet the minimum OS requirement")
elif OS == "Windows 8.1":
    print ("You meet the minimum OS requirement")
elif OS == "Windows 7":
    print ("You meet the minimum OS requirement")
elif OS == "Linux":
    print("This OS is not supported")
elif OS == "Mac":
    print("This OS is not supported")
else:
    print("Your OS does not meet the minimum requirements")
```